# How to use subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier

Tags: iphone

I have done something like

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
networkInfo.subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier = ^ (CTCarrier * carrier) 
{Do some stuff here
};
```

to get the notification when the cell service provider changes and do some tasks.The documentation says:

> A block object that is dispatched on
>   the default priority global dispatch
>   queue when the user’s cellular
>   provider information changes. This
>   occurs, for example, if a user swaps
>   the device’s SIM card with one from
>   another provider, while your
>   application is running.
>
> To handle changes in cellular service
>   provider information, define a block
>   in your application and assign it to
>   this property. The block must be
>   implemented to support being called
>   from any context.

I am not sure where to implement this in my code and will it exceute if my application is running in background or suspended.

Comment: This block gets executed if the application is running and the carrier changes.So if we want to do some stuff when the carrier changes it can be done here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block gets executed if the application is running and the carrier changes.So if we want to do some stuff when the carrier changes it can be done here.i have tested it and this works.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior on iOS5.